# Dependency Syntax tree problems

Tags: syntax

[image]

This is a Dependency syntax tree from an official website. As can be seen from this pic, "off" is deemed as a complete subtree. But when we use constituency tests to verify it, it does not perform as a constituent actually. I thought that "customer" was supposed to be a dependent of "off". Can somebody help me understand the place off "off" in this pic. Is it similar to the determiners in dependency trees?

Comment: @BillJ I don't get your analysis there. I'm pretty certain H&P would say that *off* is intransitive there, analogously to *up* in their example in [1iii] (p. 272), which they describe as intransitive in the second paragraph under *Idioms and verbal idioms* (p. 273). The example is *She gave up the struggle*.

Comment: @BillJ It's because *off* and *the customers* aren't a constituent that we can also say *Drunks could put the customers off*.

Comment: @Araucaria-him Under your analysis, the preposition "off" is a particle, a complement of "put". "The customers" is then direct object of "put". I'd go along with that.

Comment: Notice that we can also say _Drunks could also put the customers off_. Does Pa stand for particle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gets into the issue of *phrasal verbs*.

Sometimes in English, a verb connected to a preposition will act like, well, just a verb connected to a preposition. The preposition will dominate some other phrase, as prepositions normally do:

> She lived in that apartment.
> She lived, back in 2010, in that apartment.
> It was in that apartment that she lived.

However, sometimes we see a similar structure where the preposition and the following phrase aren't a constituent together:

> She handed in that assignment.
> *She handed, back in 2010, in that assignment.
> *It was in that assignment that she handed.

The second type are called *phrasal verbs*, and that's what "put off" is here:

> Drunks could fall off the staircase.
> Drunks could fall, if they're not careful, off the staircase.
> Drunks could put off the customers.
> *Drunks could put, if they're not careful, off the customers.

"Off" seems more closely bound to "put" than "the customers" here:

> It's the customers that drunks could put off.

So it makes sense to say that "off" and "the customers" both depend on "put" (in different ways).

As a side note, this phrasal vs non-phrasal distinction can in some cases distinguish homophones in English:

> He turned on his robotic ally. *(could mean either "activated" or "betrayed")*
> He turned on, next, his robotic ally. *(could only mean "activated")*
> He turned, next, on his robotic ally. *(could only mean "betrayed")*

It's one of the interesting quirks of English syntax.

Comment: And in spoken English, this ambiguity would be resolved by emphasis (and probably also context). "TURNED on" = betrayed, "TURNED ON" = activated.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question for me. It's quite inspiring.

Comment: @BillJ Are you sure you aren't thinking of "Drunks could **putt** off the customers"? :D